# When I modify a node module in my vue.js project, do I have to recompile something to get it to work? The change is not reflected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I'm working on a Vue.js project and I run into something the Bootstrap-vue module does that I'd like to get rid of. I located the place in the module that causes the behavior and commented it out. However, this is not reflected on the project. Did I miss a step here?

Comment: Do you have build process? gulp or npm run build?

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly, never a good idea to alter your node_modules packages directly,
- if you want to see the changes then run `yarn install` or `npm install` depending on what package your project is running on, after that run your local serve and changes should have taken effect

**Side note:** if you are working within a team or peer programming then I would not advise the altering of your node_modules, as the `package.json` would just overwrite the the changes on their side if using a Git environment to share code

Comment: that's right, but sometime I want to check a simple change in a module, perhaps to post the issue later on github.

Comment: Not saying its illegal to alter your node_modules, by all means test locally, but dont expect your peers to pull the same changes, can always report your test results in a thread to the author later.

Comment: I switched to patch-packer, great tool to fix the update problem.